How do traction inverters behave during regenerative braking?
I have been wanting to know exactly how regenerative braking works in an electric vehicle (3 phase) motor. It's hard to find details about it on the internet.
Recuperation utilizes the body diodes of the transistors to rectify the voltage, correct?
Are all the transistors turned off to achieve this (gates turned off?)
How does the current flow from the inductors to the battery? How does the current loop look like? Can you please draw the current path?
Are only the diodes of S1, S3 and S5 contributing to charging the battery?
EV manufacturers describe how their vehicles have different levels of recuperative braking. How is this realized?
The way I see it you either recuperate and brake or you don't. No in between. Perhaps the inverter switches fast between recuperation and traction mode?
Lastly, what exactly causes the vehicle to deccelerate? I know Lenz's law is playing a role here but I can't grasp how it's applied in this context.

1: Master of Science dissertation, Digital control techniques for grid-connected inverters, Ain Shams University, 2013. By: Ahmed Abdalrahman Ahmed

I've added green arrows to show the direction of current at a particular instant in time when the most positive terminal from the motor is indicated by the red circle and, the most negative motor terminal is indicated by the blue circle: -


Recuperation utilizes the body diodes of the transistors to rectify
the voltage, correct?

Usually but, the relevant transistors can also be activated.

Are all the transistors turned off to achieve this (gates turned off)?

They can be all turned off or, depending on which terminal is the most positive and which terminal is the most negative, two transistors can be turned on.

Are only the diodes of S1, S3 and S5 contributing to charging the
battery?

Every diode will contribute.

EV manufacturers describe how their vehicles have different levels of
recuperative braking. How is this realized?

I expect most use the methods implied in my answer.

Perhaps the inverter switches fast between recuperation and traction
mode?

Yes, it will usually switch in a micro-second or less.

Lastly, what exactly causes the vehicle to decelerate?

Mechanical force and excess rotational speed converts the motor into a generator. Energy is taken from the force and speed in the form of voltage and current. If energy is removed from something free-spinning it has to also decelerate it.

Agree with the answer from Andy.
I want to share more information:
First, refer to below photo, you can see there are two quadrants that energy can flow to Battery, II and IV. And Torque * Speed is negative sign

The motor now is generator, current source (current flow via stator windings), it is three phase current source. Then now diode take the role to rectify to DC.
In vehicle, with my knowledge about EV, need VCU/BMS corporates to charge battery.
